# text not showing over border html/css

Tags: html, css, button

I'm trying to make a simple button.  But instead of `<button>`, I'm using `<div>` and `<p>`, but the result will show up as only border, and the text won't show up over the border.

Am I doing something wrong?

Screenshot of the button:

[image: screenshot of the button]

```css
.Something4 {
  margin-top: -72px;
  margin-left: 335px;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid #E12976;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.Something4 p2 {
  margin-left: 335px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="location.href='Login.php';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="Something4">
  <p2 style="font-family: Sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-style:normal;">Login</p2>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like the background is black (and so is text by default) - have you set the text color with `color:white` or something like that?

Comment: out of curiosity - why don't you want to use the `<button>` element or `<a href="login.php">` - semantics are important for markup and then you can style however you please

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code into codepen.com.
`margin-top: -72px;` is moving your button off the screen.
The second `margin-left: 335px;` in the p2 section is moving the text out of your button.
Try removing all your margins and see how it looks:

```
.Something4 {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid #E12976;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.Something4 p2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Keep in mind the margin inside the p2 tag will not replace the margin on the border itself, and having negative margins might not always do what you think.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using semantic markup to describe the content of your page.  This helps make your content accessible and work as expected across a variety of devices and use cases that you might not be capturing.

So use an anchor tag `<a>` to link to `\login.php`, and then you can choose to style that similar to a button if you'd like.

```css
body {
    padding: 15px;
    background: #211f1f;
}

a.login-button {
    color: salmon;
    border: 1px solid salmon;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="login.php" class="login-button">Login</a>
```

Comment: thanks, i've fixed now the issue, and it was because of the margin. I didn't even realize it was in p2